# How to access the html form data in java program

Tags: java, xml, html, jakarta-ee

i have created a java project in eclipse,in this project i have an html form customer.html as shown below

```
<form>
Name :<input type="text" id="name"/>
Address: <input type="text" id="add"/>
Age:<input type="int" id="age"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="what should i call here in my program"/>
</form>
```

once the user fills the form and submits it i want to access the form field in java code is it possible.if so how or else is there anyother solution to create an xml file for this form

Comment: Provide more information about your project and what you exactly need

Comment: i am thinking of storing HTML form data into xml file

Comment: Did you see android JS interface ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" onclick="only Javascript function can be called here"/>
```

if you want to access html form elements at java code you need to submit your form at some controller or another jsp. Like..

```
<form name="new_employee" method="post" action="../admin/newEmployee.do">
  Name :<input type="text" name="employeeName"/>
  Address: <input type="text" name="add"/>
  Age:<input type="text" name="age"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

form elements can be accessed from generated request by their names like..

```
request.getParameter("employeeName");
```